# Construction of the Steinhaus probability space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, symbolic-computation

**Q:** Please let me know if the following sketch of the build-up of the [Steinhaus probability space](https://books.google.com/books?id=BgYPCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=steinhaus%20probability%20space&source=bl&ots=82BnM4H9ug&sig=ACfU3U3K1LOLJl8LuCob7W-KQXap_aCwFg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyk93j_YTrAhUEbc0KHeeICXwQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=steinhaus%20probability%20space&f=false) $(\Omega,{\cal A},P) = ((0,1), {\cal B}((0,1)), \lambda\vert_{[0,1]})$ is correct, as far as it goes:

Let the sample space $\Omega=(0,1)$, the real open interval from 0 to 1, be an open set in $2^\Re$.

Let $d(a,b)=|b-a|, a,b\in \Re$ be a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)).

Then $(\Omega,d)$ is a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space), because $(0,1)$ is a nonempty set and $d$ is a metric on $(0,1)$.

Let ${\cal O}(\Omega)$ be the [collection of all open sets](http://stat.math.uregina.ca/%7Ekozdron/Teaching/Regina/451Fall13/Handouts/451lecture05.pdf) $F \subseteq \Omega$.

Let $\Sigma({\cal O}(\Omega))$ be the [generated $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebras_generated_by_families_of_sets) of ${\cal O}(\Omega)$.

Then $(\Omega, \Sigma({\cal O}(\Omega)))$ is a [measurable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_space), because $(0,1)$ is a set and $\Sigma({\cal O}(0,1))$ is a [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) on that set.

Then ${\cal B}((0,1)) = {\cal B}(\Omega) = \Sigma({\cal O}(\Omega))$ is the [Borel $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) of $(0,1)$, because $((0,1),d)$ is a metric space and ${\cal O}((0,1))$ is the set of all open sets of $(0,1)$.

Let $\lambda: {\cal L}(\Re) \to [0,\infty)$ be the [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) on $\Re$.

Let $\lambda\vert_{(0,1)}$ be the retriction of $\lambda$ to $\Sigma({\cal O}((0,1)))$.

Then $\lambda\vert_{(0,1)}$ is a [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure), because $((0,1), \Sigma({\cal O}((0,1))))$ is a measurable space and $\lambda\vert_{(0,1)}((0,1)) = 1$.

Then $((0,1), {\cal B}((0,1)), \lambda\vert_{[0,1]})$ is a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space), since $(0,1)$ is a set, ${\cal B}((0,1))$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on that set, and $\lambda\vert_{[0,1]}$ is a probability measure on that set.

**Note:** This will seem very elementary to anybody that knows this topic.  I am new to the topic and trying to check my understanding, with a view towards implementing these definitions and constructions as Python classes and symbolic computations in [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).  So I'm trying to make each step in the build-up be something well-defined, explicit and mechanically checkable to some extent.

Comment: It all looks fine to me.